# Javascript function not running on my Flask App

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="load" class="load">
      <h3 >{{load}}</h3>
      <img  src="{{ load }}" id="image" style="height:500px;width:500px;"  />
    </div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("image").addEventListener("loadstart", refresh);

        function refresh() {
          window.location.reload();
        }
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Flask server is running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/, after every HTTP POST new image is loaded to src="{{ load }}". I'd like website to refresh by itself using function refresh, but it is not working. Does anyone has idea why?

Answer (score 0):

The image is already loaded when your script runs

Also images do not have a [loadStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/loadstart_event)

Use the window load instead

and give the user a chance to enjoy the image

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.reload(1);
  },3000)
})
```

```html
<div id="load" class="load">
  <h3>{{load}}</h3>
  <img src="{{ load }}" id="image" style="height:500px;width:500px;" />
</div>
```

You can also just load the image

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('image').src = '{{ load }}'; // you may want to add something random to not cache
  },3000)
})
```

```html
<div id="load" class="load">
  <h3>{{load}}</h3>
  <img src="{{ load }}" id="image" style="height:500px;width:500px;" />
</div>
```

Comment: Note: the real reason is that the `loadstart` event is supported only by `video` and `audio` elements.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is it possible to avoid setting timer? I just want to refresh page once after http post

Comment: @Dauros That was my first comment on the question, but then I found https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/loadstart_event but did not read further

Comment: Sure, just remove `setTimeout(function() {` and  `},3000)`

Comment: `window.addEventListener("load", function() {
        window.location.reload(1);
      })` ,but it keeps refreshing page for all of the time ;/

Comment: `I'd like website to refresh by itself using function refresh` - exactly what you ask

Comment: I just want to refresh page once after server receives new image and then stop refreshing and wait for another new image to refresh it once again

Comment: How do you know there is a new image?

Comment: I use turbo_flask: `@app.context_processor
def inject_load():
    global image
    return {'load': 'static/uploads/' + image}` and after every request src="{{ load }}" is changed in index.html properly(I checked it via CTRL +U), so the only thing I need is to refresh once

Comment: Refresh once will load one image and then what? If you want to keep showing new images you need setInterval and the second script if the url of the image stays the same otherwise the first script with set timeout